# Macro gives error for no reason while creating a drop down data validation?

Tags: excel, validation, vba

```
Range("C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Materials"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

I am trying to contruct a data validation to a one cell with macro. So that when you choose the material the graph will automatically change. Materials in the code is the data validation range, I named the range hoping that resolves the error.

So the main problem is that while the macro is running it gives "Run time error 1004". If I debug and put my yellow cursor to a few step back and go with f8, it works perfectly. I take this code from record macro. Code seems right but I don't know why macro gives error about it.

Comment: Delete the line `Range("C4").Select` and replace `With Selection.Validation` with `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Validation` Also change "Sheet1" to the relevant sheet name and try again

Comment: And finally see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) :)

Comment: Unfortunately not worked :( . I know there is a lot going on avoiding select but avoiding it does not solve problems all the time. If you know how to use it properly, it will work with no problem. I have 1 month work of macro using a lot of select and activate, no problem at all. In your solution, it is not recognizing the thisworkbook since it works on module. Even though i deleted it the program gives error always at the

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Materials"


code. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Ok. Couple of questions... `1` Is the code in the same workbook which has `Materials` named range? `2` Is the code trying to add the DV List in the same workbook from where it is run? `3` If the answer to the above questions is "Yes" then  do you have multiple workbooks opened? If yes, close them and try again.

Comment: there is no code in workbooks. It is on module of a workbook. Which uses other workbooks to construct another result workbook.

The data validation part is on the result workbook. The materials table is at one sheet and I am trying to construct the data validation to another sheet.

Comment: `The data validation part is on the result workbook. The materials table is at one sheet and I am trying to construct the data validation to another sheet.` And hence you need to fully qualify the `Range("C4")` object and `"=Materials"`

Comment: `1` What is the name of the workbook and worksheet where `Range("C4")` resides `2` What is the name of the workbook and worksheet where `Materials` resides ? `3` What is the name of the workbook where the code resides

Comment: 1) ROL workbook, sheet1
2)ROL workbook, 6monthsConsumption
3)MainCode workbook

Comment: Just to confirm your worbooks are "ROL.xls*" and "MainCode.xls*" \?

Comment: ROL.xlsx       MainCode.xlsm

Comment: One moment. testing the code before posting an answer... I am assuming that the "materials" is a named range and not a table

Comment: no no assume that is a table

Comment: but i can change it to a named range anyway

Comment: Can you check the code that I posted with the named range.

Comment: btw man the thing is code is right i think. Like i say it gives error (application.events=false by the way and all the excels are minimized), when I click the ROL excel, the code continues to work

Comment: You may have to refresh the page to see the answer

Answer (score 0):

ok I found it.

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Materials
```

since Materials is a table now on, I should have deleted the extra = and "

note: with this it gives no error but couldn't read the data from materials table also.

Comment: You never mentioned anywhere in your question that `Materials` is a table? You said it is a `Named Range`

Comment: it was a named range, I am just trying different things. It doesn't work anyway

Comment: the thing interesting about that is when I debug and just re-do the things after I maximize the workbook window (even though it is the only workbook that is active) it works. Other than that it gives error. Just makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me.

**My Assumptions:**

1. `Materials` is a named range.
2. `Workbooks("ROL.xlsx")` is open in the same Excel instance.

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbDV As Workbook
    Dim wsDV As Worksheet

    Set wbDV = Workbooks("ROL.xlsx")
    Set wsDV = wbDV.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsDV.Range("C4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Materials"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try, but like I say the excel couldn't see the code I think. Sheets and workbooks are already arranged. But wait like 2 minutes I will try. Thanks for all the effort btw, it means a lot.

Comment: it gives the same error. Like I say I need to make excel understand that the workbook is opened. There is no problem with the definitions of ranges or workbooks.

Comment: Like I said it works for me. Is Workbooks("ROL.xlsx") open?

Comment: If it is not open then change the line `Set wbDV = Workbooks("ROL.xlsx")` to `Set wbDV = Workbooks.Open("C:\ROL.xlsx")` I have used `C:\`. You have to replace it with the full path..

Comment: ı changed it already, but like i say problem is same and i solved it really unlogically. you can check the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 Workbooks(strii).Activate
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlEqual, Formula1:="=Materials"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

maximizing the excel works just fine. Don't know why but it works

Comment: I just checked. I had missed the part where you said that the workbook is minimised. My code works just fine when the workbook is maximised. So all you had to do was add the maximize code to my code ;)